# Trigonometric Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[image]

Would someone please explain the steps taken to arrive at the third and fourth step? Why is it $(1-u^2)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For the third step, $u=\cos x$, $-du=\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$, and $1-u^2=\sin^2x$.

For the fourth step, $\frac{(1-u^2)(-\mathrm{d}u)}{u}=\left(\frac{-1+u^2}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u=\left(\frac{-1}{u}+\frac{u^2}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u$...

Answer (score 2):

because $u = \cos x \to \sin^3 x = \sin^2 x \cdot \sin xdx = -(1-u^2)du$